# Inner joins with Rails active record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I'm new to Rails and have been working through various books and tutorials. I've got a simple (ish) setup with the models and schemas below. 
I'm trying to acquire the user details plus the usergroup_membership ID. I think I have my models setup correctly for what I want to achieve (the relationships are as they appear, users belong to groups via usergroup_memberships - nothing fancy).
Using 'rails db' I can use raw SQL to get the recordset I need but I can't figure out how to do it the Rails way.

My basic classes

```
Class User
has_many :usergroup_memberships
has_many :usergroups, :through => :usergroup_memberships

Class Usergroup
has_many :usergroup_memberships, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :users, :through => :usergroup_memberships

Class UsergroupMembership
belongs_to :usergroup
belongs_to :user
```

SQL which works

```
SELECT users.*, usergroup_memberships.id 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN usergroup_memberships ON usergroup_memberships.user_id = users.id 
WHERE usergroup_memberships.usergroup_id = 1;
```

The above SQL is fine and returns the recordsets with the joined usergroup_memberships.id tagged on the end. Any help or docs on how to approach this via Rails is most appreciated.

Comment: For help on queries in rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html ; Your associations look like a `has_and_belongs_to_many` one, look at it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Comment: Thanks - this is something I had a bit of a battle with when I was starting. I've ended up with a full blown table rather than a join table which upsets the HABTM naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

You can do experiments like this in the so called [rails console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html).

If you are in your apps directory, you can start the rails console with:

```
rails c
```

Wait for the prompt! First you will need to get a user:

```
u = User.first
```

Then you can get the usergroups quite easy:

```
g = u.usergroups
```

You will find yourself always in the console for testing such things, which you can use in your application e.g.: getting the first users usergroups:

```
User.first.usergoups
```

However, let me recommend the gem: [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry). By using this gem ( just put it into your Gemfile ) you can create breaking points inside you application for debugging purposes, which will result in a rails console. For example in a controller method you can just say:

```
binding.pry
```

When this line gets executed, the rails server will switch into debug mode and halts at the break point and you are able to see all the variables, methods defined in that scope.

Comment: Hi and thanks. The console is indeed very valuable and so far I've spent hours in it :) I've tried things such as 'x= User.first.usergroups' and that's fine. but when I get to User.first.usergroups.includes or joins it starts to fall apart a little

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I don't get what you want to do exactly, pls try to form it more clear! What is the output you are looking for?

Comment: So to break it up a little - I'd like the output of `Usergroup.find(groupID).users` (which works) but with the additional usergroup_memberships.id field tagged on the end of the recordset. I guess I could map the attribute but this seems like the wrong way to do it?

Comment: Well, you could just use:
`m = Usergroup.find(groupID).usergroup_memberships` then, you can access `m.id` and `m.user` too. What you wanna do with the result? Mb if you tell me i can get closer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found something that works well for me:

```
@blah = Usergroup.find(groupID).usergroup_memberships.includes(:user)
```

Then, to access the user details:

```
@blah[i].user.email
```

(and thanks for your comments - @Baldrick - I think my model my well be a bit broken / unconventional, something to keep in mind for the next project).